# Place CWAC CameraFragment inside other fragment for preview size

Tags: android, android-fragments, commonsware-cwac

I would like to place the preview window inside an activity at a specified position. I have tried adding a CameraFragment directly in the Activity. This will open the Preview. But on "takePicture" it will crash with the preview must be opened first.

How would I position the camera preview at a specific position or inside another fragment for positioning?

Answer (score 0):

> But on "takePicture" it will crash with the preview must be opened first.

It is possible that this reflects a bug somewhere in the library. Are you sure that you are not calling `takePicture()` too soon? If it is tied to a button, usually the preview will show up first. I have [an outstanding issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/179) to add better callbacks to let you know when it is safe to call `takePicture()` (e.g., to enable/disable a button).

> How would I position the camera preview at a specific position

The same way you would any other widget: put the `CameraFragment` or `CameraView` inside some container, with `android:layout_*` attributes (plus attributes on the container) that control its position.

> or inside another fragment

I have not tried `CameraFragment` with nested fragments. In theory, this should work out of the box on API Level 17+. Nested fragments prior to that require the Android Support package's backport of fragments, so you would want to clone `CameraFragment` and change its superclass to be `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and fix up other methods as needed. If you happen to be using ActionBarSherlock, the `CameraFragment` in the `camera-v9` project uses `SherlockFragment`, which in turn uses the fragment backport.

Comment: I will have a look and create a separate project to see if it crashes. But I do see the preview picture for several seconds before pressing takePicture. It might be me just being to noobish at Android and using wrong fragment or something. I will get back with log.

Comment: @user2130951: "But I do see the preview picture for several seconds before pressing takePicture" -- that should be more than plenty. The other risk is in calling `takePicture()` before the preview has started up again after a previous `takePicture()` call.